# What should have the responsibility to create dynamic views?

Tags: mvvm, mvp

Using MVVM or MVP patterns, it doesn't really matter, which entity should have the responsibility to create dynamically view as response to an event?

For example, let's say that a button is pushed and now a new gui must be opened for the first time, where should I place the factory call to create the new view?

Creating a view from a presenter that has nothing to do with the view itself looks ugly to me. Mediate the button view and use a factory inside the mediator? Use a factory inside a command?

Note: I meant to remove the MVVM part, but then I received the first answer, which I assigned as correct because I like the general idea (can be applied to MVP as well). However if you have other clean ways to solve the problem, I will be glad to hear it from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question aims at whether it goes to **M**odel, **V**iew or **V**iew**M**odel the anser is: Neither.

MVVM is a design pattern, which dictates how Views are separated from code (View and Presentation logic in particular).

However, it do not dictate on how or where to implement your business and application logic. MVVM is usually used together with other design patterns, like n-tier or DDD (Domain Driven Design).

n-Layer usually consists of

- Application Layer is where your Application services, like Dependency Injection, Navigation services, ViewModel Locators, View Factories in your case are. This is also where Views are located at in the n-tier model
- Presentation Layer is where your presentation logic is (your ViewModels in particular)
- Business/Domain Layer is where your business logic is (Models, domain services, like the `OrderService` in an shopping application)
- Infrastructure Layer is where your infrastructure is, in particular abstractions to the database (Repositories, CQRS) or webservices, stuff that depends on a certain technology, like SignalR, ASP.NET Identity, OWIN etc. to name a few

This makes it much clearer on how to separate your responsibilities and how to keep your application portable.

As an example, you would have an Application that implements Presentation Layer, Business Layer (the core of your app) and some Infrastructure (i.e. webservice communication). This parts can be easily reused, when you port your App from an Desktop Application to an Windows Phone Application for example.

You'll be able to reuse your whole domain layer and your presentation layer (ViewModels) and most of the infrastructure (i.e. you may have to switch MSSQL as data access layer for SQLite or SQLCompact).

However the Application Layer is **very** specific to the application you make and not be reusable. When you have a Desktop application you want to port to Windows Phone, you have to create the application layer from scratch (i.e. choose an DI Framework compatible with WinPhone, the navigation is very different and the View specific, XAML/UI capabilities are different too etc.).

Each of them is usually in it's own assembly to make it easier to enforce this model. For example, in your Presentation assembly (where your ViewModels are) you don't have an reference to the Application Layer assembly. Now when you try to use a type from the application assembly, you'll realize that you can't access it's namespace/type and this tells you: "Uh-oh. You were about to violate the MVVM/n-tier model" and that whatever you attempted, was wrong.

**Finally to your initial question**

Ideally, you would have an `INavigationService` interface in your presentation layer (ViewModel) assembly. But you would implement this service in the Application Layer, because `NavigationService` requires the knowledge of the Views in order to work, but the `ViewModel` do not allow such knowledge.

The `NavigationService` then would (on a navigation request), call your `IViewFactory` (which can also be implemented in the application layer or if it's meant to be reusable with other platforms in the infrastructure layer) and it would dynamically construct your View.

From your ViewModel you would just do something like `navigationService.Navigate<CustomerViewModel>(customerId)`. Rest is up to the concrete implementation in the application/infrastructure layer.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I meant to remove the MVVM part because I knew it would have been confusing, but then I forgot about that. I guess your solution would apply with a MVP scenario too tho. However I still wonder if the viewmodel should have the direct responsability to create a view, even if through a service. I wonder if it should just send an event and something else intercept it and decide to open a new view.

Comment: In the above scenario ViewModel wouldn't even know, if a view would be created dynamically or not, as it would just invoke the navigation. The navigation service then decides if it has to be created dynamically or use an existing view to display it. And the Navigation is implemented on a different layer

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, it's just that the concept of navigation itself is not abstract already. Why should the viewmodel know that the navigation service itself exists?

Comment: Navigation is essential part of an (MVVM) Application and at any time, there will only just be one navigation service that handles the navigation. And as your navigation demands grow, it's unavoidable that the ViewModels become navigation aware, be it to handle From/To Navigation events or to control the lifetime of the ViewModel. And while you can make To-Navigation work with events, cancellation of navigation is hard thing to do.

Comment: Imagine having a ContentControl which displays different views for the current entity and allows editing. You change something and don't save it and then click a button to navigate to a different entity's Edit ViewModel. With event you'll have hard time to cancel/delay the navigation until the user can interact (save or discard changes to previous ViewModel). Prims uses `INavigationAware` interface with `NavigateFrom(..)` (called in the current View/ViewModel before navigation occurs) and `NavigateTo(..)` (called in new ViewModel after navigation occured). Pretty messy with events

Comment: Also as a last note. My rule for events/services: Events if it's supposed for 0 or more listeners. Service if it's exactly 1 listener or 1 and more. An injected navigation service is a mandatory (constructor dependencies are always mandatory) and hence always guaranteed that it's always be there. With events you have no guaranty if anyone or anything will listen to the event or not. Events for optional stuff, services for mandatory. Event/Messages are good for `UserChangedEvent` notifications

Comment: yes although this goes against the inversion of flow control design that I like a lot...generally I think so far your solution is the best tho.